# Thinking_Sphinx Error in 'Report_Core'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, thinking-sphinx

I have a thinking-sphinx app and oddly enough the files in /db/sphinx/development/ have not been initialized.

I have a separate app where they HAVE been, but I am not sure why. I don't recall doing anything different.

Does anyone know how to create these files or if they are app specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `db/sphinx/development` usually contains the sphinx index on your development machine, if you have built it. You can do this in ThinkingSphinx by creating your configuration file with `rake ts:conf`, afterwards you can generate the Sphinx index with `rake ts:index`. Sphinx need to be installed correctly on your machine, of course.